# Filter a column in logs using an interpolated string with awk

Tags: android, bash, awk

I have adb logs from Android phone that looks like this:

```
02-11 18:16:54.737 24875 24875 I MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
```

Third element is a pid.

What I do is first I grab the pids

```sh
list="/"`adb shell ps | grep -E 'audioserver|system' | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' '|' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev`"/"
```

This provide me something like `/77|471|472|473|474|491|499|503|505|506|507|537|627/`

Then I try to filter logs:

```sh
$ adb logcat | awk -v list="$list" '$3 ~ list'
```

But I get nothing displayed. If I do :

```sh
$ adb logcat | awk '$3 ~ /77|471|472|473|474|491|499|503|505|506|507|537|627/'
```

I have output.

1. Why I have no output?
2. Is it possible to rewrite this in a more simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create your regex with delimiters `/`. Just create a regex with alternations and **make sure to use anchors** to avoid getting a match like `5085` when you have `508` in alternation:

```
echo '02-11 18:16:54.737 24875 24875 I MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex' |
awk -v re='503|505|506|507|537|627|24875' ' $3 ~ "^(" re ")$" '
```

```
02-11 18:16:54.737 24875 24875 I MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it fix it and I prefer the way your wrote it. I changed your script because I do not know the content of `re`. So I did ```list="`adb shell ps | awk '$9 ~ /audio|sytem/' | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' '|' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev`" && adb logcat | awk -v list="$list" '$3 ~ "^(" list ")$"'```. And it works. :)